# Are there anti entropic agents

Tags: everyday-life, entropy

The entropy of an isolated system always increases,

Considering an intelligent actor in the system who can organise different objects in the system, doesnt the measure of disorder reduce albeit for short periods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maxwell demon : how can the demon move the door without doing any work ?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59242/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the intelligent actor is subject to the second law of thermodynamics. In short, it shows that you can't conceive of a computer/brain that can perform the necessary computation+work to the objects around it without an added increase in entropy. Remember computers/brains produce heat, and that means disorder.

What you are asking about is called [Maxwell's demon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon) and if you are interested 
in the entropy related to computation, check out Shannon entropy. Because the information in a computer/brain has to be stored physically somehow, Shannon entropy has physical consequences.

Btw, the law states that entropy never decreases, not that it always increases.

Comment: Que? What does gravity have to do with anything?